# Finding a number with the help of another function

Tags: python

I have a function that receives an argument for money, the second one is for interest (like when you put money on the bank) and the 3rd one is for the amount of years you wish to deposit your money. The function will return the money you'll get at the end. This is the function:

```
def value(money,interest,years):
    return money * (1 + interest) ** years
```

I want to create a second function that receives the two first arguments and then asks you the money you wish to get at the end. Given that it will return the amount of years needed to do so. This is what I got so far but it ain't working because the input that gives me has more than two decimals and I want a method where the years can be as precise as possible instead of me having to increase the years by 0.01. Any help?

```
def find(money,interest):
    wish = eval(input("How much money do you wish to get?: "))
    stonks = wish / money
    years = 0
    while wish >= value(money,interest,years):
        years += 0.01
    return years
```

I'll give an example of the outputs that it was given to me:

```
find(100,0.03)
How much money do you wish to get?: 200
24
```

Comment: You need to look up the various forms of the compound interest equation.  This is on-line research, rather than a Stack Overflow issue.  Once you find it, if your implementation has a bug, *then* you likely have a question for us.

Comment: There is a mathematical solution to this as @Prune pointed out, but if you want to solve it [numerically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) there are many methods. For a simple one I would start with [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) which doesn't have the risk of diverging.

Comment: Use `float` to convert a string to a number, not `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

You need logarithm to do that:

```
def find(money,interest):
    wish = eval(input("How much money do you wish to get?: "))
    stonks = wish / money
    
    return math.log(stonks, 1+interest)
```